# Can Any one offer me a sample in gdi+ to draw an image on canvas?

Tags: gdi+, matrix, rotation

I need to draw an image with a certain angle on a canvas, it need to rotate angle N , and its center is on x, y

```
        Matrix myPathMatrix;
        myPathMatrix.Translate(x, y, MatrixOrderAppend);
        myPathMatrix.Rotate(angle, MatrixOrderAppend);
        canvas->SetTransform(&myPathMatrix);
        Draw(canvas);// draw the image
        myPathMatrix.Rotate(-angle, MatrixOrderAppend);
        myPathMatrix.Translate(-x, -y, MatrixOrderAppend);
        canvas->SetTransform(&myPathMatrix);
```

But I find the img rotate by the top left corner, I need the image rotate with its center.
How can I do this?
many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change rotation "center" which is by default top left.
Here some code I found on the net:

```
private Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap b, float angle)
{
  //create a new empty bitmap to hold rotated image
  Bitmap returnBitmap = new Bitmap(b.Width, b.Height);
  //make a graphics object from the empty bitmap
  Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(returnBitmap);
  //move rotation point to center of image
  g.TranslateTransform((float)b.Width/2, (float)b.Height / 2);
  //rotate
  g.RotateTransform(angle);
  //move image back
  g.TranslateTransform(-(float)b.Width/2,-(float)b.Height / 2);
  //draw passed in image onto graphics object
  g.DrawImage(b, new Point(0, 0)); 
  return returnBitmap;
}
```